# How to configure SAML Federation between Azure Active Directory (as IDP) and an Enterprise Application using apis?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to configure Azure Active Directory as Identity Provider for Enterprise application(s) with SAML Federation. Its clear how to do it in Azure portal UI. However, is there a way to do all that via Azure APIs? Do such Azure APIs exist as part of azure subscription?

I'm currently going through - Azure Active Directory Graph API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you currently cannot configure a custom SAML application via an API (what you can do today in the Azure portal via Enterprise apps).

Comment: Still not possible ? :(

Comment: Correct, still not possible.

Comment: Damn. Even in powershell?

Comment: PowerShell would call the API. If there is no API, there isn't PowerShell either.